# C++ std::function bind from derived class

Tags: c++, std-function, stdbind

If I had a base class MessageWrapper, with a child class SetConfigurationData, why does binding with a child class parameter not work?

Shouldn't it work polymorphically?

```
Class MessageHandler
{
    public:
    void RegisterHandler(std::function<void(MessageWrapper &)> callback_)
    {}
};

class Testing
{
    public:

    Testing(MessageHandler &handler_)
        : m_Handler(handler_)
    {
        m_Handler.RegisterHandler(std::bind(&Testing::TestMessageHandler, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    }

    void TestMessageHandler(SetConfigurationData &msg_)
    {}

    MessageHandler m_Handler;
};
```

I get the error:
"Failed to specialize function template 'unkown-type std::invoke(*Callable* &&, Types &&..)'

It works if I do this:

```
void TestMessageHandler(MessageWrapper &msg_)
{}
```

Comment: Title nitpick: you're not binding *from* a derived class, you're trying to bind a covariant function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymorphism cannot work like this. I will explain with an example. Let's say the function.

```
void TestMessageHandler(SetConfigurationData &msg_)
```

has something specific to the child object in it's body. Say

```
msg.child_method()
```

Now since RegisterHandler callback_() takes base class as argument, what should it do with this "msg.child_method()" call since it's not a base class method ?

Now, what happens if we do it the other way round. The following works.

```
class MessageWrapper
{
};

class SetConfigurationData : public MessageWrapper
{
    public:
    void RegisterHandler(std::function<void(SetConfigurationData&)> callback_)
    {}
};

class MessageHandler
{
};

class Testing
{
    public:

        Testing(SetConfigurationData &handler_)
            : m_Handler(handler_)
        {
            m_Handler.RegisterHandler(std::bind(&Testing::TestMessageHandler, this, std::placeholders::_1));
        }

        void TestMessageHandler(MessageWrapper &msg_)
        {}

        SetConfigurationData m_Handler;
};
```

Even though TestMessageHandler takes MessageWrapper as argument, u can bind it to callback_ which takes Child class (SetConfigurationData) as argument.

Comment: This answer is so close to clearly explaining the situation, but it's missing a very important detail: that the caller can invoke the function with a reference to a `MessageWrapper` which isn't a `SetConfigurationData`. E.g. `class OtherMessage : public MessageWrapper {}; OtherMessage foo; callback_(foo);` -- This satisfies the contract of the `MessageWrapper&` argument type, but does not satisfy `SetConfigurationData&`, which is why the covariant function conversion is disallowed.